# How to create a dates series that gives me only the end of the month days?

Tags: matlab, date, series

How do I create a dates series that gives me only the end of the month days?
i.e.

```
31/01/1993
28/02/1993
...
31/01/2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **calendar** function:

```
for year = 1993:2013
    for month = 1:12
        lastday = max(max(calendar(year,month)));
        fprintf('%02d/%02d/%04d\n',lastday,month,year)
    end
end
```

You can of course store result in matrix (or cell array) by changing fprintf with sprintf:

```
dates = char(zeros(12*21,10));
idx = 0;
for year = 1993:2013
    for month = 1:12
        idx = idx + 1;
        lastday = max(max(calendar(year,month)));
        dates(idx,:) = sprintf('%02d/%02d/%04d',lastday,month,year);
    end
end
```

---EDIT---

I've found thath there is aslo [eomday](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/eomday.html) function. So instead of line:

```
lastday = max(max(calendar(year,month)));
```

You can use:

```
lastday = eomday(year,month);
```

To see the algorithm of eomday function type in MATLAB:

```
open eomday
```

Comment: PROBLEM : How do I do it for many years? I tried BB=datestr(datenum(1993:2013,2:13,1)-1,24); but gives me just the 31 Jan of each year

Comment: You can use datenum in this way: datestr(datenum(1993,2:(12*20+2),1)-1,24) - it means that you provide year and number of months for which you want the dates.

Answer (score 3):

The easy way would be to use the start of month days and subtract one. So, for instance:

```
datevec(datenum(1993,2,1)-1);
```

This would give you `1993 01 31`. It is fairly simple to then do the same for each following month. e.g.

```
datenum(1993,2:13,1)-1;
```

would give you the end of month days for the whole of 1993.

EDIT:

As Luis pointed out, if you want the dates as formatted strings, as in the original question, you would use `datestr`:

```
% The '24' causes datestr to use a predefined format of the form 'dd/mm/yyyy'
datestr(datenum(1993,2:13,1)-1,24)
```

EDIT2:

To do multiple years, you can just increase the number of months. MATLAB's datenum function is clever - if you give it a date `datenum(1993,14,1)` it will return `1994/2/1`, so if you wanted every month from 1993-2013 (20 years, so 240 months) you would use

```
datestr(datenum(1993,2:241,1)-1,24)
```

Comment: +1 for that "-1" idea to get last day of previous month!

Comment: To get the OP's desired result, combine with `datestr` with format 23: `datestr(datenum(1993,2:13,1)-1,23)`

Comment: Good point, I amended my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks. Small correction: for 'dd/mm/yyyy' you need 24. 23 gives the US format.

Comment: PROBLEM : 
How do I do it for many years? I tried BB=datestr(datenum(1993:2013,2:13,1)-1,24);  but gives me just the 31 Jan of each  year.

Comment: Simple, if you are starting at 1993, for each year you would add 12 to the final value in the month column. For instance `datestr(datenum(1993,2:25,1)-1,24)` would get you the days from 1993 and 1994, and so on.